# Past or perfect tense

Tags: grammar

Which is the correct one: "I've missed my flight" or "I missed my flight"?

Comment: let's say that i had a flight today, but i woke up late and missed it. If i call a friend of mine to tell them about it, should i say "i've missed my flight" or "i missed my flight"?

Comment: You should edit that detail into the question as comments can get removed.

Comment: Please use a capital letter for the pronoun I. Also, this question should go on ELL, not here. :)

Comment: When in doubt, *don't use a Perfect verb form*.

Comment: In British English: (speaking that morning) "Oh no! I've missed my flight." (speaking later) "I didn't go to France after all because I overslept and missed my flight."

Answer (score 0):

I would consider either one correct, although they have slightly different meanings.

"I've missed my flight" implies that the missing of the flight is still ongoing.  If you just ran up to the gate and noticed that the plane was taking off, this would probably be most appropriate.  But even if it's hours later, and you're still dealing with the aftermath of the missed flight (finding a place to stay, booking a new flight, informing people of your whereabouts), it could still apply.

"I missed my flight" implies a specific incident that happened in the past.  "Remember that time last year when I missed my flight?"  If you are no longer living the experience of missing the flight, you would probably use this phrase instead.  (Even if it was only 10 minutes ago, but you've accepted it and moved on.)

What it boils down to, is whether you are still experiencing the "missing" of the flight, whatever that might entail.  If you are still experiencing it, you would use "I've", but if it's over and done with, you would use "I".